# Power function of fixed numbers.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

Prove that $3^x-4^x+2x4^{x-1}\le0$, where $x\in[-0.5,0]$.Here is it's [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5Ex-4%5Ex%2B2*x*4%5E%28x-1%29%20from%20-1%20to%200).

I tried to do it by first and second derivative test but it involves $log$  which make the expression more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
f(x)=\frac x2+\left(\frac34\right)^x
$$
is a [Convex Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function). This
can be shown by noting that its second derivative is positive:
$$
\begin{align}
f''(x)
&=\log\left(\frac34\right)^2\left(\frac34\right)^x\\
&\ge0
\end{align}
$$
Thus, if $f(a)\le1$ and $f(b)\le1$ then for all $x$ between $a$ and $b$, $f(x)\le1$.

Since $f(-0.5)=-\frac14+\frac2{\sqrt3}\lt1$ (since $\frac43\le\frac{25}{16}$) and $f(0)=1$, we have that for all $-0.5\le x\le0$,
$$
\frac x2+\left(\frac34\right)^x\le1
$$
which means that
$$
3^x\le\left(1-\frac x2\right)4^x
$$
which implies
$$
3^x-4^x+2x4^{x-1}\le0
$$

Comment: I see that this is along the same lines as TonyK's answer, and I was about to delete it, but since there is some extra detail in this answer, I will leave it.

Answer (score 3):

If $y \in [0,\frac12)$, then $\left(\frac43\right)^y \le 1 + \frac12y$, because $\left(\frac43\right)^y$ is a convex function of $y$, and the inequality is true at the end-points $0$ and $\frac12$.

Now putting $x=-y$, we have, for $x \in [-\frac12,0]$,

$$\left(\frac34\right)^x \le 1 - \frac12x$$

Multiplying by $4^x$: $$3^x \le 4^x(1-\frac12x)$$

Rearranging, and using $\frac12 4^x = 2\cdot 4^{x-1}$:
$$3^x-4^x+2x4^{x-1}\le0$$

Comment: +1  Your first inequality can also be got from Bernoulli's inequality...

Comment: @Macavity: Bernoulli shows that $\left(1+\frac13\right)^y\ge1+\frac13y$ and $\left(1+\frac12\right)^y\ge1+\frac12y$. Neither of these show that $\left(1+\frac13\right)^y\le1+\frac12y$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @robjohn You miss for $y \in [0, 1]$, Bernoulli's inequality works in the other direction - i.e. $$(1+\tfrac13)^y \le 1+\frac{y}3 \le 1+\frac{y}2$$

Comment: @Macavity: Ah, silly me. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Using the first derivative you can see that the function is increasing on the given interval. Since $f(0) \leq 0$, the function is everywhere below 0 on the given interval.

Comment: The first derivative is rather messy...

Comment: how we can say it is increasing as I said derivative is more complicated then given function.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen